# unattend.xml works in uefi not in bios

Tags: deployment, unattended

hello I have an unattend_uefi.xml file this looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<unattend xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:unattend">
    <servicing>
        <package action="configure">
            <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft-Windows-Client-LanguagePack-Package" version="10.0.17134.1" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="en-US" />
        </package>
        <package action="configure">
            <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft-Windows-ProfessionalEdition" version="10.0.17134.1" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="" />
        </package>
        <package action="configure">
            <assemblyIdentity name="Package_for_KB4287903" version="10.0.1.0" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="" />
        </package>
        <package action="configure">
            <assemblyIdentity name="Package_for_RollupFix" version="17134.112.1.7" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="" />
        </package>
    </servicing>
    <settings pass="windowsPE">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-International-Core-WinPE" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <SetupUILanguage>
                <UILanguage>en-US</UILanguage>
            </SetupUILanguage>
            <InputLocale>en-US</InputLocale>
            <SystemLocale>nl-NL</SystemLocale>
            <UILanguage>en-US</UILanguage>
            <UserLocale>nl-NL</UserLocale>
        </component>
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <DiskConfiguration>
                <Disk wcm:action="add">
                    <CreatePartitions>
                        <CreatePartition wcm:action="add">
                            <Order>1</Order>
                            <Type>Primary</Type>
                            <Size>500</Size>
                        </CreatePartition>
                        <CreatePartition wcm:action="add">
                            <Order>2</Order>
                            <Extend>false</Extend>
                            <Type>EFI</Type>
                            <Size>100</Size>
                        </CreatePartition>
                        <CreatePartition wcm:action="add">
                            <Order>3</Order>
                            <Size>300</Size>
                            <Type>MSR</Type>
                        </CreatePartition>
                        <CreatePartition wcm:action="add">
                            <Order>4</Order>
                            <Extend>true</Extend>
                            <Type>Primary</Type>
                        </CreatePartition>
                    </CreatePartitions>
                    <ModifyPartitions>
                        <ModifyPartition wcm:action="add">
                            <Order>2</Order>
                            <Format>FAT32</Format>
                            <Label>System</Label>
                            <PartitionID>2</PartitionID>
                        </ModifyPartition>
                        <ModifyPartition wcm:action="add">
                            <Format>NTFS</Format>
                            <Label>WinRE</Label>
                            <Order>1</Order>
                            <PartitionID>1</PartitionID>
                            <TypeID>DE94BBA4-06D1-4D40-A16A-BFD50179D6AC</TypeID>
                        </ModifyPartition>
                        <ModifyPartition wcm:action="add">
                            <Order>3</Order>
                            <PartitionID>3</PartitionID>
                        </ModifyPartition>
                        <ModifyPartition wcm:action="add">
                            <PartitionID>4</PartitionID>
                            <Order>4</Order>
                            <Letter>C</Letter>
                            <Label>Windows</Label>
                            <Format>NTFS</Format>
                        </ModifyPartition>
                    </ModifyPartitions>
                    <DiskID>0</DiskID>
                    <WillWipeDisk>true</WillWipeDisk>
                </Disk>
                <WillShowUI>OnError</WillShowUI>
            </DiskConfiguration>
            <ImageInstall>
                <OSImage>
                    <InstallTo>
                        <DiskID>0</DiskID>
                        <PartitionID>4</PartitionID>
                    </InstallTo>
                </OSImage>
            </ImageInstall>
            <UserData>
                <AcceptEula>true</AcceptEula>
            </UserData>
            <WindowsDeploymentServices>
                <Login>
                    <Credentials>
                        <Domain>test</Domain>
                        <Password>password is here/Password>
                        <Username>sgadmin</Username>
                    </Credentials>
                </Login>
                <ImageSelection>
                    <InstallImage>
                        <ImageGroup>Windows 10 64 bit</ImageGroup>
                        <ImageName>windows</ImageName>
                    </InstallImage>
                    <InstallTo>
                        <DiskID>0</DiskID>
                        <PartitionID>4</PartitionID>
                    </InstallTo>
                </ImageSelection>
            </WindowsDeploymentServices>
        </component>
    </settings>
    <settings pass="specialize">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <TimeZone>W. Europe Standard Time</TimeZone>
        </component>
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-UnattendedJoin" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <Identification>
                <Credentials>
                    <Domain>test.nl</Domain>
                    <Password>installerkkddk</Password>
                    <Username>wdsinstaller</Username>
                </Credentials>
            </Identification>
        </component>
    </settings>
    <settings pass="oobeSystem">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-International-Core" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <InputLocale>en-US</InputLocale>
            <SystemLocale>nl-NL</SystemLocale>
            <UILanguage>en-US</UILanguage>
            <UserLocale>nl-NL</UserLocale>
        </component>
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <OOBE>
                <HideEULAPage>true</HideEULAPage>
                <HideOnlineAccountScreens>true</HideOnlineAccountScreens>
                <HideWirelessSetupInOOBE>true</HideWirelessSetupInOOBE>
                <ProtectYourPC>1</ProtectYourPC>
                <HideLocalAccountScreen>true</HideLocalAccountScreen>
                <HideOEMRegistrationScreen>true</HideOEMRegistrationScreen>
                <UnattendEnableRetailDemo>false</UnattendEnableRetailDemo>
                <VMModeOptimizations>
                    <SkipAdministratorProfileRemoval>true</SkipAdministratorProfileRemoval>
                    <SkipNotifyUILanguageChange>true</SkipNotifyUILanguageChange>
                    <SkipWinREInitialization>true</SkipWinREInitialization>
                </VMModeOptimizations>
            </OOBE>
            <UserAccounts>
                <LocalAccounts>
                    <LocalAccount wcm:action="add">
                        <Password>
                            <Value>YQBkAG4AbwB3ADIAawBQAGEAcwBzAHcAbwByBCAH</Value>
                            <PlainText>false</PlainText>
                        </Password>
                        <Group>Administrators</Group>
                        <DisplayName>admin</DisplayName>
                        <Name>admin</Name>
                    </LocalAccount>
                </LocalAccounts>
            </UserAccounts>
            <RegisteredOrganization>test</RegisteredOrganization>
            <RegisteredOwner>test</RegisteredOwner>
        </component>
    </settings>
    <settings pass="auditSystem">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <UserAccounts>
                <AdministratorPassword>
                    <Value>YQBkAG4AbwB3ADIAawBBAGQAbQBpAG4AaQBzAHDKJFJDFhAHQAbwByAFAAYQBzAHMAdwBvAHIAZAA=</Value>
                    <PlainText>false</PlainText>
                </AdministratorPassword>
            </UserAccounts>
        </component>
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="wow64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <AutoLogon>
                <Password>
                    <Value>YQBkAG4AbwB3ADIAawBQAGEAcwBzAHcAbwByBCAH</Value>
                    <PlainText>false</PlainText>
                </Password>
                <Username>administrator</Username>
                <Enabled>true</Enabled>
            </AutoLogon>
        </component>
    </settings>
    <cpi:offlineImage cpi:source="wim:c:/users/sgouman/downloads/install.wim#Windows 10 Enterprise" xmlns:cpi="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:cpi" />
</unattend>
```

and the bios unattend.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<unattend xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:unattend">
    <servicing>
        <package action="configure">
            <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft-Windows-Client-LanguagePack-Package" version="10.0.17134.1" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="en-US" />
        </package>
        <package action="configure">
            <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft-Windows-ProfessionalEdition" version="10.0.17134.1" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="" />
        </package>
        <package action="configure">
            <assemblyIdentity name="Package_for_RollupFix" version="17134.112.1.7" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="" />
        </package>
        <package action="configure">
            <assemblyIdentity name="Package_for_KB4287903" version="10.0.1.0" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="" />
        </package>
    </servicing>
    <settings pass="windowsPE">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-International-Core-WinPE" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <SetupUILanguage>
                <UILanguage>en-US</UILanguage>
            </SetupUILanguage>
            <InputLocale>en-US</InputLocale>
            <SystemLocale>nl-NL</SystemLocale>
            <UILanguage>en-US</UILanguage>
            <UserLocale>nl-NL</UserLocale>
        </component>
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <DiskConfiguration>
                <Disk wcm:action="add">
                    <CreatePartitions>
                        <CreatePartition wcm:action="add">
                            <Order>1</Order>
                            <Type>Primary</Type>
                            <Size>500</Size>
                        </CreatePartition>
                        <CreatePartition wcm:action="add">
                            <Order>2</Order>
                            <Extend>true</Extend>
                            <Type>Primary</Type>
                        </CreatePartition>
                    </CreatePartitions>
                    <ModifyPartitions>
                        <ModifyPartition wcm:action="add">
                            <Format>NTFS</Format>
                            <Label>System</Label>
                            <Order>1</Order>
                            <PartitionID>1</PartitionID>
                            <Active>true</Active>
                        </ModifyPartition>
                        <ModifyPartition wcm:action="add">
                            <Order>2</Order>
                            <Format>NTFS</Format>
                            <Label>Windows</Label>
                            <PartitionID>2</PartitionID>
                            <Letter>C</Letter>
                        </ModifyPartition>
                    </ModifyPartitions>
                    <DiskID>0</DiskID>
                    <WillWipeDisk>true</WillWipeDisk>
                </Disk>
                <WillShowUI>OnError</WillShowUI>
            </DiskConfiguration>
            <ImageInstall>
                <OSImage>
                    <InstallTo>
                        <DiskID>0</DiskID>
                        <PartitionID>2</PartitionID>
                    </InstallTo>
                </OSImage>
            </ImageInstall>
            <UserData>
                <AcceptEula>true</AcceptEula>
                <Organization>test</Organization>
            </UserData>
            <WindowsDeploymentServices>
                <Login>
                    <Credentials>
                        <Domain>test</Domain>
                        <Password>password is here</Password>
                        <Username>sgadmin</Username>
                    </Credentials>
                </Login>
                <ImageSelection>
                    <InstallImage>
                        <ImageGroup>Windows 10 64 bit</ImageGroup>
                        <ImageName>windows</ImageName>
                    </InstallImage>
                    <InstallTo>
                        <DiskID>0</DiskID>
                        <PartitionID>2</PartitionID>
                    </InstallTo>
                </ImageSelection>
            </WindowsDeploymentServices>
        </component>
    </settings>
    <settings pass="oobeSystem">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-International-Core" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <InputLocale>en-US</InputLocale>
            <SystemLocale>nl-NL</SystemLocale>
            <UILanguage>en-US</UILanguage>
            <UserLocale>nl-NL</UserLocale>
        </component>
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <OOBE>
                <HideEULAPage>true</HideEULAPage>
                <HideOnlineAccountScreens>true</HideOnlineAccountScreens>
                <HideWirelessSetupInOOBE>true</HideWirelessSetupInOOBE>
                <ProtectYourPC>1</ProtectYourPC>
                <HideLocalAccountScreen>true</HideLocalAccountScreen>
                <HideOEMRegistrationScreen>true</HideOEMRegistrationScreen>
                <UnattendEnableRetailDemo>false</UnattendEnableRetailDemo>
                <VMModeOptimizations>
                    <SkipAdministratorProfileRemoval>true</SkipAdministratorProfileRemoval>
                    <SkipNotifyUILanguageChange>true</SkipNotifyUILanguageChange>
                    <SkipWinREInitialization>true</SkipWinREInitialization>
                </VMModeOptimizations>
            </OOBE>
            <UserAccounts>
                <LocalAccounts>
                    <LocalAccount wcm:action="add">
                        <Password>
                            <Value>YQBkAG4AbwB3ADIAawBQAGEAcwBzAHcAbDHDJDAGQA</Value>
                            <PlainText>false</PlainText>
                        </Password>
                        <Group>Administrators</Group>
                        <DisplayName>admin</DisplayName>
                        <Name>admin</Name>
                    </LocalAccount>
                </LocalAccounts>
            </UserAccounts>
            <RegisteredOrganization>test</RegisteredOrganization>
            <RegisteredOwner>test</RegisteredOwner>
        </component>
    </settings>
    <settings pass="auditSystem">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <UserAccounts>
                <AdministratorPassword>
                    <Value>YQBkAG4AbwB3ADIAawBBAGQAbQBpAG4AaQBzAHQAcgBhAHQAbwBDJDJDYQBzAHMAdwBvAHIAZAA=</Value>
                    <PlainText>false</PlainText>
                </AdministratorPassword>
            </UserAccounts>
        </component>
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="wow64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <AutoLogon>
                <Password>
                    <Value>YQBkAG4AbwB3ADIAawBQAGEAcwBzAHcDJDJDAGQA</Value>
                    <PlainText>false</PlainText>
                </Password>
                <Username>administrator</Username>
                <Enabled>true</Enabled>
            </AutoLogon>
        </component>
    </settings>
    <settings pass="specialize">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-UnattendedJoin" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <Identification>
                <Credentials>
                    <Domain>hier staat normaal een domeinnaam</Domain>
                    <Password>install</Password>
                    <Username>wdsinstalledsfsdfsdfr</Username>
                </Credentials>
            </Identification>
        </component>
    </settings>
    <cpi:offlineImage cpi:source="wim:c:/users/sgouman/downloads/install.wim#Windows 10 Enterprise" xmlns:cpi="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:cpi" />
</unattend>
```

i changed the passwords a bit in both file but on my end they are the same on each file:

For some reason the uefi works fine and creates an admin account.

but whenever i run it in bios using the unattend_bios.xml it starts the install automaticly on the correct drive.
but it doesnt cvreate and admin account and skip the eula and all the other oobe settings.

Comment: Can you send me a copy of the panther logs?